# Quickly change a photoshop layer's position in stack to right before another layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Sometimes you need to move a layer to right before another layer in the Layers panel, I usually do that by Drag and Drop, but it's not that efficient if a large stack with hundreds of layers, wondering if there is a shortcut will do that quickly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following keystrokes but I am not sure how much easier will they be if you indeed have "hundreds" of layers. You may want to consider whether that many layers are really needed. That said, here are the keyboard shortcuts:

1. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to move from one layer to the next, up or down
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to move a layer up or down

The first simply changes the target layer while the second one actually moves the layer.